# How can I protect the part of my piece I don't want painted when painter's tape won't stick?

Tags: technique, paint, process, painting

I'm building a dog house for my backyard and have put a water seal on the floor and porch, since those will be most exposed to the elements. Now I need to paint the walls and went to put painter's tape over the parts I don't want painted, but the tape doesn't stick to the sealed wood.

What are my options here?

Comment: Paint more carefully? I don't mean this to sound trite, but that's how things were done prior to painter's tape being a thing. Some painters still rely on this a surprising amount to save on tape, taping time and the possibility of paint lift-off when you eventually peel off the masking tape. Sure it'll slow you down but it's just one dog house, it won't be a big deal. If you do get some overpaint or spatters A) I'm sure your dog won't mind ^_^ but more importantly B) there's a darned good chance they won't stick well given tape doesn't!

Comment: I painted my turned porch posts a couple of years ago. Put down some drop cloths to protect the floor, but simply used a 1" cut angle brush, care, and patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back before quality painter's/masking tape was available to the masses, my dad always used a painter's straight edge for cutting into corners and wall/ceiling junctions:

[image: painter's straight edge from Amazon]

<sup>Source: [amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B0Z5DFG)</sup>

They're available in different lengths (this particular one comes in 12" and 24" sizes) and are much faster and easier to use than painter's tape... especially when it doesn't stick :)

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see if the paint will stick to the water seal. If it does, you can try wax, which is what I use where panels connect to stiles/rails in panel and frame construction. You can use painters tape on the unsealed wood before laying down the wax and then take it off to get a sharp edge.

Comment: Well, it seems the OP has already tested and the tape does _not_ stick to the water seal. Since it's already been sealed, it seems that it's also a bit late for wax, too, doesn't it?